# socket structure : casting?

Tags: c, sockets, struct, casting

## Context

I am self-learning how sockets work.
Admitted, I am not a C guru, but learn fast.

I read this page :

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/topic/rzab6/rzab6xafunixsrv.htm

## Problem

I am stuck at this line :

```
rc = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, SUN_LEN(&serveraddr));
```

I just cannot figure what we get from this cast (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr.

## My test so far :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>


int main(void)
{

/*JUST TESTING THE CAST THING NOTHING ELSE HERE*/

struct sockaddr_in localaddr ;
struct sockaddr_in * mi;
struct sockaddr * toto;

localaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

localaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
localaddr.sin_port = 38999;

/* DID I DEFINED MI CORRECTLY ? */
mi = (struct sockaddr*)&localaddr;
toto = (struct sockaddr*)&localaddr;

printf("mi %d\n",mi->sin_family);
printf("mi %d\n",mi->sin_port);
printf("toto %d\n",toto->sa_family);
/*ERROR*/
printf("toto %d\n",toto->sa_port);

}
```

## SUM UP

Could someone please tell me what is really passed to the bind function concerning the structure cast ?

What members do we have in that structure ?

How can I check it ?

Thanks

Comment: The cast is needed because `(struct sockaddr *)` is actually an union of different structs for the different addressings schemes. Take a look inside the header files, and you'll see. BTW: main() should return int.

Comment: `void main()` is not a valid main signature.  `int main(int, char**)` and `int main(void)` are.

Comment: You don't need the cast in `mi = (struct sockaddr*)&localaddr;`: The types are already the same for the RHS and LHS.

Comment: The function prototype for `bind()` expects a `struct sockaddr *`. But this structure is a union of different structures that allow a program to reference the proper member when opening for example a `unix domain socket` or an `inet socket` as in your code.

Comment: I was about to reply, but Paul Griffiths said it best in his response below: 'It's basically a way of getting polymorphism [in C] when you don't actually have real OOP constructs."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's `struct sockaddr`:

```
struct sockaddr {
    uint8_t      sa_len;
    sa_family_t  sa_family;
    char         sa_data[14];
};
```

and, for instance, here's `struct sockaddr_in`:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    uint8_t        sa_len;
    sa_family_t    sa_family;
    in_port_t      sin_port;
    struct in_addr sin_addr;
    char           sin_zero[8];
};
```

and `struct sockaddr_in6`:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 {
    uint8_t         sa_len;
    sa_family_t     sa_family;
    in_port_t       sin_port;
    uint32_t        sin6_flowinfo;
    struct in6_addr sin6_addr;
};
```

You'll note that they all share the first two members in common. Thus, functions like `bind()` can accept a pointer to a generic `struct sockaddr` and know that, regardless of what specific `struct` it actually points to, it'll have `sa_len` and `sa_family` in common (and "in common" here means "laid out the same way in memory", so there won't be any weirdness where both `struct`s *have* an `sa_family` member, but they're in totally different places in the two different `struct`s. Technically `sa_len` is optional, but if it's not there, none of the `struct`s will have it, so `sa_family` will still be aligned in the same way, and often the datatype of `sa_family_t` will be increased to make up the difference in size). So, it can access `sa_family` and determine exactly what type of `struct` it is, and proceed accordingly, e.g. something like:

```
int bind(int socket, const struct sockaddr *address, socklen_t address_len) {
    if ( address->sa_family == AF_INET ) {
        struct sockaddr_in * real_struct = (struct sockaddr_in *)address;

        /*  Do stuff with IPv4 socket  */

    }
    else if ( address->sa_family == AF_INET6 ) {
        struct sockaddr_in6 * real_struct = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)address;

        /*  Do stuff with IPv6 socket  */

    }

    /*  etc  */
}
```

(Pedantic note: technically, according to the C standard [section 6.5.2.3.6 of C11], you're only supposed to inspect common initial parts of `struct`s like this if you embed them within a `union`, but in practice it'll almost always work without one, and for simplicity I haven't used one in the above code).

It's basically a way of getting polymorphism when you don't actually have real OOP constructs. In other words, it means you don't have to have a bunch of functions like `bind_in()`, `bind_in6()`, and all the rest of it, one single `bind()` function can handle them all because it can figure out what type of `struct` you actually have (provided that you set the `sa_family` member correctly, of course).

The reason you need the actual cast is because C's type system requires it. You have a generic pointer in `void *`, but beyond that everything has to match, so if a function accepts a `struct sockaddr *` it just won't let you pass anything else, including a `struct sockaddr_in *`. The cast essentially tells the compiler "I know what I'm doing, here, trust me", and it'll relax the rules for you. `bind()` *could* have been written to accept a `void *` instead of a `struct sockaddr *` and a cast would not have been necessary, but it wasn't written that way, because:

1. It's semantically more meaningful - `bind()` isn't written to accept *any* pointer whatsoever, just one to a `struct` which is "derived" from `struct sockaddr`; and
2. The original sockets API was released in 1983, which was before the ANSI C standard in 1989, and its predecessor - K&R C - just didn't have `void *`, so you were going to have to cast it to something in any case.

Comment: Yes, That is what I said in my first comment.

Comment: One might also ask why BSD didn't use a union in the first place. I suspect it's because they didn't want `<sys/socket.h>` to have to maintain a list of all the `sockaddr_`* types in existence but I have no proof. The GNU system (gcc+glibc) actually uses a fancy thing called a "transparent union" so you can leave out the casts, as long as you `-D_GNU_SOURCE`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley: Good question, I'm not sure either, but I'd guess the same, and because trying to stuff all the structs into an actual union in the header could cause problems with existing programs if you ever wanted to add new structs to the family, particularly any that had to make the union bigger.

Comment: Your comment lead me to sockaddr.h and i saw the macros defining the rest. Sockets's code is at first really difficult to grasp when learning how things work but when you get a lead, it becomes affordable. Thanks a lot Paul.

Answer (score 2):

Casts appear in socket code because C doesn't have inheritance.

`struct sockaddr` is an abstract supertype of `struct sockaddr_in` and friends. The syscalls take the abstract type, you want to pass an actual instance of a derived type, and C doesn't know that converting a `struct sockaddr_in *` to a `struct sockaddr *` is automatically safe because it has no idea of the relationship between them.

Comment: Ok, so what is exactly passed ? the plain sockaddr_in structure ? How the system deals with sa_data ? I think I will need to ask another question in another thread I think : what is the point to cast from a structure to another.

Comment: The address is what's actually passed, since the function accepts a pointer. You have a `struct sockaddr_in`, and the function accepts a pointer to a `struct sockaddr`, so you have to cast the address of your struct to type `struct sockaddr *` when you pass it.

Comment: Is passed a pointer. That cast is used only to avoid compiler warnings.

Comment: @Larry You pass exactly what you have, no data is changed anywhere at all. It's just a pointer type recast to shut up the compiler warnings.

Comment: @Larry you started out saying you're "not a C guru", so maybe an analogy in a language you know better would help. What language do you prefer? (Hopefully you aren't starting with C - nobody ever said C was a good "intro to programming" language!) Are the words "inheritance" and "polymorphism" flying way over your head? ... And by the way, I endorse Paul Griffiths' separate answer as the full-length version of mine.

Comment: I use lua, python. Inheritance and polymorphism are well know mechanisms to me. It is just that I had a lot of pain to understand the cast thing and why it is necessary. Compiler warnings, ok, but that only cause literaly flies over my head!

Comment: Thanks Wumpus and the others I get it now !